# ¿Cómo mandar mas de un objeto a una tabla con jsp desde un ciclo for iterator?

Tags: java, jsp, web

Buenas amig@s quiero mostrar en una tabla una lista de registros de articulos asociados a una tienda, ejecutando mi query mediante el gestor de BD me muestra el resultado que deseo, cuando en mi clase con mi metodo de busqueda de articulos ejecuto el query, en el log me muestra todos los registros, posteriormente cuando guardo los resultados y recorro mediante un ciclo FOR ITERATOR, en efecto en el LOG me guarda todos los registros, PERO, cuando retorno el contenido de mi ciclo, solo me manda y me muestra en la vista el ultimo registro, ¿ a que podra deberse esto? 
aca les dejo el metodo con el query, mi ciclo FOR mas el return, espero puedan ayudarme  o darme alguna sugerencia, gracias.

```
public Producto consultaProducto(EntityManager em, String codigoBarra,
        String sucursal) {

    String query2 = "SELECT   temp.codigoPrincipal,"
         +"temp.descripcionCorta,"
         +"temp.descripcionLarga,"
         +"im.dept,"
         +"vi.vat_rate,"
         +"rfr.selling_retail,"
         +"TO_CHAR (rpile.detail_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),"
         +"TO_CHAR (rpile.detail_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),"
         +"rpile.promo_comp_id,"
         +"rpile.promo_id,"
         +" DECODE (uil.uda_value,"
            +"     '0',"
            +"     'Normal',"
            +"     '4',"
            +"     'Pesable',"
            +"     '7',"
            +"     'Procesado')"
           +" estado,"
        +" rfr.simple_promo_retail,"
        +" NULL,"
        +" im.standard_uom,"
        +" im.MFG_REC_RETAIL,"
        +" s.store_name"
 +" FROM                        item_master im"
                        +"   JOIN"
                             +" (SELECT   DECODE (im.item_number_type,"
                                           +"     'ITEM', im.item,"
                                              +"  im.item_parent)"
                                         +"  codigoPrincipal,"
                                       +" im.item_desc descripcionLarga,"
                                      +"  im.short_desc descripcionCorta"
                               +"  FROM   item_master im"
                               +" WHERE   im.item = ?1) temp"
                         +"  ON (im.item = temp.codigoPrincipal)"
                       +" JOIN"
                        +"   uda_item_lov uil"
                       +" ON (im.item = uil.item AND uda_id = 3)"
                    +" LEFT JOIN"
                    +"   item_loc il"
                    +" ON (im.item = il.item)"
                  +" LEFT JOIN"
                  +"   rpm_future_retail rfr"
                  +" ON (rfr.item = il.item AND rfr.location = il.loc)"
              +" LEFT JOIN"
              +"    rpm_promo_item_loc_expl rpile"
              +" ON (rfr.item = rpile.item AND rpile.location = rfr.location)"
              +" AND TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE (rpile.detail_start_date,"
              +" 'DD/MM/YYYY')AND  TO_DATE (rpile.detail_end_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')"
           +" JOIN"
             +"  store s"
           +" ON (il.loc = s.store)"
        +" JOIN"
        +" vat_item vi"
        +" ON (im.item = vi.item AND s.vat_region = vi.vat_region)"
 +"WHERE       store = DECODE (?2, '0', s.store, ?2)"
         +"AND (TO_DATE (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(rfr.action_date)) >= '0'"
         +"AND VI.VAT_TYPE IN ('R', 'B')"
         +"AND vi.active_date IN"
                +"  (SELECT   MAX (active_date)"
                 +"    FROM   vat_item vi1"
                  +"  WHERE       vi.item = vi1.item"
                         +"   AND vi.vat_type = vi1.vat_type"
                          +"  AND vi1.create_date <= TRUNC (SYSDATE)"
                          +"  AND vi.vat_region = vi1.vat_region)";

    Producto productoRetornar = new Producto();
    List<Object> objetos=new ArrayList();
    try
    {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(query2);
    query.setParameter(1, codigoBarra);
    query.setParameter(2, sucursal);
            //query.setParameter(3, sucursal);

    logger.info("INFORMACION DEL QUERY METODO CONSULTA PRODUCTO" +query);

            objetos = query.getResultList();

            logger.info("INFORMACION DEL CONTENIDO DE LOS OBJETOS CONSULTA PRODUCTO" +objetos);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        productoRetornar.setMensaje("No se puede conectar"+e.getMessage());
    }

        for(Iterator<Object> it = objetos.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            List<Object> resultElement = (List<Object>) it.next();

            String codigoPrincipal = null;
            try {
                codigoPrincipal = resultElement.get(0).toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String descripcionCorta = null;
            try {
                descripcionCorta = resultElement.get(1).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String descripcionLarga = null;
            try {
                descripcionLarga = resultElement.get(2).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String departamento = null;
            try {
                departamento = resultElement.get(3).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String iva = null;
            try {
                iva = resultElement.get(4).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String precio = null;
            try {
                precio = resultElement.get(5).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String fechaInicioPromocion = null;
            try {
                fechaInicioPromocion = resultElement.get(6).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String fechaFinPromocion = null;
            try {
                fechaFinPromocion = resultElement.get(7).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String codigoComponente = null;
            try {
                codigoComponente = resultElement.get(8).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String codigoPromocion = null;
            try {
                codigoPromocion = resultElement.get(9).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String estado = null;
            try {
                estado = resultElement.get(10).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String precioPromocion = null;
            try {
                if(codigoPromocion!= null)
                    precioPromocion = resultElement.get(11).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String frecuencia = null;
            try {
                frecuencia = resultElement.get(12).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String uom = null;
            try {
                uom = resultElement.get(13).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String pvJusto = null;
            try {
                pvJusto = resultElement.get(14).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            String nombreSucursal = null;
            try {
                nombreSucursal = resultElement.get(15).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            logger.info("INFORMACION DEL CICLO FOR METODO CONSULTA PRODUCTO" +resultElement);
            if(!objetos.isEmpty())
            {
                productoRetornar.setCodigoPrincipal(codigoPrincipal);
                productoRetornar.setDescripcionCorta(descripcionCorta);
                productoRetornar.setDescripcionLarga(descripcionLarga);
                productoRetornar.setDepartamento(departamento);
                productoRetornar.setIva(iva);
                productoRetornar.setPrecio(precio);
                productoRetornar.setFechaInicioPromocion(fechaInicioPromocion);
                productoRetornar.setFechaFinPromocion(fechaFinPromocion);
                productoRetornar.setCodigoComponente(codigoComponente);
                productoRetornar.setCodigoPromocion(codigoPromocion);
                productoRetornar.setEstado(estado);
                productoRetornar.setPrecioPromocion(precioPromocion);
                productoRetornar.setFrecuencia(frecuencia);
                productoRetornar.setUom(uom);
                productoRetornar.setMensaje("");
                productoRetornar.setPvJusto(pvJusto);
                productoRetornar.setNombreSucursal(nombreSucursal);
            }

            logger.info("METODO CONSULTA PRODUCTO CONTIENE LA INFORMACION QUE SE RETORNA  A EL CONTROLADOR"+productoRetornar);    
    return productoRetornar;

}
```

esta es la seccion del codigo en donde realizo la iteracion

`for(Iterator<Object> it = objetos.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            List<Object> resultElement = (List<Object>) it.next();`

EN esta nueva edicion agrego la informacion en mi servlet que no me permite castear la clase Producto a Listreconocia mi metodo, ahora en el servlet me aparece el siguiente error

`incompatible Types: List<Producto>cannot be converted to Producto`

el error claro dice que no son compatibles,asumo porque la clase Producto (que es en donde estan declaradas todas mis variables con getters y setter de la BD) es de tipo objetos y no lista, a pesar de que casteo el llamado a el metodo en el servlet de la siguiente manera

producto = (Producto) consultaRms.consultaProductos(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);

me compila pero igual me arroja el error en el monitor de weblogic, porque asumo que al correr en el servidor de aplicaciones de weblogic vuelve a compilar el mismo WAR

aca esta el codigo completo del servlet en donde hago el llamado al metodo y luego de recibido mando la respuesta a la vista mediante AJAX

```
@RequestMapping("/ajax_consultaProducto")
public ModelAndView consultaProducto(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                  @RequestParam("buscarProductoInput") String codigoBarra,
                                  @RequestParam("comboboxSucursales") String sucursal,
                                  @RequestParam("IpCC") String ipControlador
) throws Exception {

    logger.info("LLamado a metodos consultaProducto y buscarEstatusProducto Parametros: " + em + ", " + codigoBarra + ", " + sucursal);
    int mensajeEnviar;
    codigoBarra = codigoBarra.replace(" ", "");
    IConsultaProductosRms consultaRms = new ConsultaProductosRms();
    Producto producto = null;
    Map<Integer, Object> mapRetorno = null;
    producto = consultaRms.consultaProductos(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);
    mensajeEnviar = consultaRms.buscarEstatusProducto(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);
    producto.setStatusProducto(Integer.toString(mensajeEnviar));
    mapRetorno = transformObjectToTreeMap(producto);
    logger.info("Producto devuelto transformado en map:  " + mapRetorno);
    return new ModelAndView("ajax_sucursales", "lista", mapRetorno);

}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar por favor el código del jsp en donde estas iterando.

Comment: listo ya en la edicion agregue la seccion del codigo amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que cuando haces el bucle estás capturando la lectura de cada objeto del iterador sobre un único objeto, esto es, cada vez que recorres el bucle estas sobreescribiendo todos los datos.

El log te muestra todos porque cada vez que haces el bucle lo imprimes, pero al final sólo devuelves el último, en vez de una lista con todos los que deberías haber ido cargando con el bucle.

Para arreglarlo haz lo siguiente:

1. Previo a iniciar el bucle declara e instancia una lista para cargar todos los productos:

   ```
   List<Producto> listaProductos = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. Nada mas iniciar el bucle declara un nuevo producto para que en cada ciclo cargues los datos del producto en un nuevo objeto:

   ```
   productoRetornar = new Producto();
   ```
3. (OPCIONAL) Si quieres reducir código puedes cargar directamente los atributos en `productoRetornar` no hace falta cargarlos en varaibles auxiliares. Además puedes usar un mismo bloque `try` y si salta alguna excepción tratarla como necesites.
4. El final de la carga de los datos añades el producto recien cargado a la lista:

   ```
   listaProductos.add(productoRetornar);
   ```
5. Cuando termines el método devuelves la lista, en vez del producto de la última iteración.

   ```
   return listaProductos;
   ```
6. Deberás cambiar la firma del método porque ya no devuelves lo mismo:

   ```
   public List<Producto> consultaProducto(EntityManager em, 
       String codigoBarra, String sucursal)
   ```

*NOTA: Según he estado mirando tu código me parece que te falta una llave para cerrar el bucle `for`. Tal cual está debería de terminarse el bucle en la primera iteración, aunque no se si has puesto el código completo, pero ten cuidado con ello.*

**EDITO**

Cuando haces un cambio hay que revisar más partes del código claro. Si antes esperabas un producto y ahora recibes una lista hay que implementarlo.

El problema lo tienes en estas líneas:

```
Producto producto = null;
producto = consultaRms.consultaProductos(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);
```

Como se puede ver declaras un objeto de clase `Producto` cuando en realidad debes declarar una lista. Cámbialo:

```
List<Producto> productos = null;
productos = consultaRms.consultaProductos(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);
```

Esto te puede afectar en que luego cuando lo tratas quizás debas hacerlo con un `for` ya que tienes varios productos:

```
for(Producto producto : productos){
    producto.setStatusProducto(Integer.toString(mensajeEnviar));
}
```

No obstante si has cambiado la firma del código como te decía no debería compilarte a menos que tengas otro método llamado igual que devuelva un producto y no una lista de productos.

Comment: amigo Awes0meM4n muchas gracias por tu ayuda, acabo de implementar tu sugerencia, pero me esta presentando problemas de compatibilidad de la clase Productos a List<Producto> en el servlet, en la edicion agregue la informacion al respecto, espero seguir contando con tu ayuda

Comment: en efecto @Awes0meM4n se corrigio el problema de compatibilidad, solo que en el metodo setStatusProducto me arroja incompatibilidad ya que manda un Int con mensaje enviar  :S

Comment: Eso es porque ahora estás intentado usar un método del objeto producto sobre una lista de productos que, por supuesto, no tienen ese método. Ahí deberás hacer otro bucle for o lo que debas. Eso ya no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta que has hecho. Si encuentras algún otro problema en el futuro puedes hacer otra pregunta.

Comment: si debere tratar con la manera de la busqueda de estatus, gracias